# How do I pass array value in SOAPUI?

Tags: soap, soapui, soap-client

Here I need to pass "UserIDs" as an array using SOAPUI. I don't know the way I am doing is correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your WSDL file?

Comment: Attached is my complete file. I meant you can see everything in image other then the first line.

Comment: Nothing is attached.  I ask you this because we need to see what XML format your SOAP service is expecting.  It likely expects something like this: `<UserIDs><UserID>1234</UserID><UserID>56789</UserID></UserIDs>`

Comment: Ohh! Got it but WSDL file is secure I meant client file so I can't share. but I want to know can i test that wsdl file using SOUPUI by passing an array value.

Comment: Got it let me do that. Attaching format in 5 min

Comment: every where it is like, <input> <soap12:body use="literal"/></input> No where i can see like userid

Comment: But please let me know, Normally how can we pass array value here.

Comment: What I already mentioned is my best guess here.  We need to see the WSDL to determine the exact format your SOAP service expects.

Comment: Here is the format of Userids, <xsd:element name="UserIDs" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:string"/>

Comment: Try making a SOAP call with only one user id.  This eliminates the uncertainty surrounding how to handle multiple user ids in a single string.  When that works, come back here and we'll find a way to handle more than one user id.